# File naming error in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello all I am having a problem when exporting a named file to the device internal storage for my apps Sqlite database name.
I am getting the error

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/:/09/12/2017-JDO.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

when trying to name the file /09/12/2017-JDO.
I am using `File.pathSeparator()` with the passed in file name but still am not having any luck. I think it has to do with the / in the file name which is the reason why I tried the `File.pathSeparator()` to begin with since I want that option for naming the file if the user wants to include the date in that format or in combination with the /.

Here are some code snippets of the methods I am using to try and accomplish this and to show what I am trying to do.

```
 /*
    This method saves and exports the current database to the device's internal Downloads folder
    This is the default named database
    */
    public void backUpDatabase() {
        /* Open your local db as the input stream */
        DBHelper anotherDbHelper = null;
        try {
            try {
                anotherDbHelper = new DBHelper(ExistingTallyActivity.this);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String path = null;
        if (anotherDbHelper != null) {
            path = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(anotherDbHelper.getDatabaseName()));
        }

        File dbFile = null;
        if (path != null) {
            dbFile = new File(path);
        }

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            if (dbFile != null) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String outFileName = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/Pipe_Tally");

        /* Open the empty db as the output stream */
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Transfer bytes from the input-file to the output-file */
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    try {
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Close the streams */
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (anotherDbHelper != null) {
            anotherDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    /*
    This method renames the database to what the user inputs they want. Note: The original db is
    still present and stored in the Downloads folder as well.
     */
    public void renameDbFile(String desiredDbName) {
        /* Open your local db as the input stream */
        DBHelper dbHelperToRename = null;
        try {
            try {
                 dbHelperToRename = new DBHelper(ExistingTallyActivity.this);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String pathRenamed = null;
        if (dbHelperToRename != null) {
            pathRenamed = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(dbHelperToRename.getDatabaseName()));
        }

        File dbFileRenamed = null;
        if (pathRenamed != null) {
            dbFileRenamed = new File(pathRenamed);
        }

        FileInputStream fisRenamed = null;
        try {
            if (dbFileRenamed != null) {
                fisRenamed = new FileInputStream(dbFileRenamed);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Here is where the db is renamed by the user by inserting the passed in string to the method */
        String outFileNameRenamed =
                (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/"+desiredDbName+".db");

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream outputStreamRenamed = null;
        try {
            outputStreamRenamed = new FileOutputStream(outFileNameRenamed);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Transfer bytes from the input-file to the output-file */
        byte[] bufferRenamed = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try {
            if (fisRenamed != null) {
                while ((length = fisRenamed.read(bufferRenamed)) > 0) {
                    try {
                        if (outputStreamRenamed != null) {
                            outputStreamRenamed.write(bufferRenamed, 0, length);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Close the streams */
        try {
            if (outputStreamRenamed != null) {
                outputStreamRenamed.flush();
                outputStreamRenamed.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (fisRenamed != null) {
                fisRenamed.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (dbHelperToRename != null) {
            dbHelperToRename.close();
        }
    }

    /*
    This method exports the database into CSV format as well by naming it the passed in string value
    for the desired name.
    */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void saveDbAsCsv(String desiredCsvName) {
        /* Getting a instance of the DbHelper class right here. */
        DBHelper dbhelperCsv = null;
        try {
            dbhelperCsv = new DBHelper(ExistingTallyActivity.this);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Original name of the file dir where the db will be stored in csv format. (Just like SQLite) */
        String pathRenamedCsv = null;
        if (dbhelperCsv != null) {
            pathRenamedCsv = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(dbhelperCsv.getDatabaseName()));
        }
        /* Creating a File type here with the passed in name from above from the string */
        File dbFile = getDatabasePath(pathRenamedCsv);
        /*
        Appending the desired name to the Downloads Directory here, which is where the new file
        will be written
        */
        String renamedCsvName = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/"+desiredCsvName);
        File exportDir = new File(String.valueOf(renamedCsvName));
        if (!exportDir.exists())
        {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        /*
        Critical .csv extension here. Took me a while originally to figure out where to pass this
        in at. Was at first passing it into the renamedCsvName up above and it was just returning
        a folder with the .csv extension and not the file contained withn.
        */
        File file = new File(exportDir, desiredCsvName+".csv");
        try
        {
            /* Passing in the string value of the file to an instance of the CsvWriter class */
            CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(String.valueOf(file));
            SQLiteDatabase db = null;
            if (dbhelperCsv != null) {
                db = dbhelperCsv.getReadableDatabase();
            }
            /* Getting a cursor from the database table Tally_File */
            Cursor curCSV = null;
            if (db != null) {
                curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tally_File",null);
            }
            if (curCSV != null) {
                csvWriter.writeRecord(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            }
            if (curCSV != null) {
                while(curCSV.moveToNext())
                {
                    /* Exporting all the columns here to write out to the csv file */
                    String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2),
                            curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4), curCSV.getString(5),
                            curCSV.getString(6), curCSV.getString(7), curCSV.getString(8),
                            curCSV.getString(9), curCSV.getString(10), curCSV.getString(11),
                    curCSV.getString(12), curCSV.getString(13), curCSV.getString(14), curCSV.getString(15),
                    curCSV.getString(16)};
                    /*
                    Critical here as I was not at first calling the writeRecord that accepted the
                    String[] array and was calling the toString() method on it and only getting a large
                    array.
                    */
                    csvWriter.writeRecord(arrStr);
                }
            }
            csvWriter.close();
            if (curCSV != null) {
                curCSV.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception sqlEx)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error naming file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Here is where I am calling the methods and passing in the desiredName for naming the file/Db, which is switch case dependent on a menu selection, all within the same activity.

```
case R.id.menu_save_and_export:
                Thread threadMenuSaveAndExport = new Thread();
                /*
                This method verifies user permissions then calls the backUpDatabase() method to
                backup the original db file before the user renames it, if desired.
                */
                verifyStoragePermissions(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                        /* Calling this method here to backup the current database*/
                        backUpDatabase();
                    }
                });
                /* Loading the view of activity_database_name with this LayoutInflater*/
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(ExistingTallyActivity.this)
                        .inflate(R.layout.activity_database_name,null);
                /*This editText handles the input from the user for their chosen db name*/
                mEtCustomDbName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCustomDbName);
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExistingTallyActivity.this);
                /* Taken from the strings.xml file. Says Name Database Prior To Export */
                alert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.name_your_db));
                alert.setView(view);
                /* Using the global "Ok" string from strings.xml */
                alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.global_ok_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                /* Passing in the results of the editText to a string here*/
                        String userDefinedDbName = mEtCustomDbName.getText().toString().trim();
                                /*
                                Calling this method to rename the existing db to what the user input
                                Note: The original db remains in the same folder, as it was previously
                                backed up from the backUpDatabase() method above. Using the if statement
                                below to check for a empty string and if it is, the file is not renamed.
                                Both situations display custom toast message dependent on which executes.
                                Also implementing the File.separator method to help with File naming
                                issues on the Android "Unix-like" filesystem
                                */
                        if (userDefinedDbName.length() > 0) {
                            /* Naming to a .db extension with this method. Works with SQLite */
                            renameDbFile(File.pathSeparator+userDefinedDbName);
                            /* Naming to a .csv extension with this method for working with Excel */
                            saveDbAsCsv(File.pathSeparator+userDefinedDbName);
                            Toast.makeText(ExistingTallyActivity.this,
                                    /* Using the "Database Saved" string from strings.xml */
                                    getResources().getString(R.string.database_saved),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(ExistingTallyActivity.this,
                                    /* Using the "Database Not Saved" string from strings.xml */
                                    getResources().getString(R.string.database_not_saved),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                /* Using the global "Cancel" string from strings.xml */
                alert.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.global_cancel_text), null);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                AlertDialog showAlert = alert.create();
                showAlert.show();
                threadMenuSaveAndExport.start();
                break;
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated with this as I do want to be able to use the naming with / if desired as an option. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to create the path `/:/09/12/` in `/storage/emulated/0/Download`?

Comment: @Rotwang. Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that as well. Thanks